# How to run test cases in a specified file?

Tags: go

My package test cases are scattered across multiple files, if I run `go test <package_name>` it runs all test cases in the package.

It is unnecessary to run all of them though. Is there a way to specify a file for `go test` to run, so that it only runs test cases defined in the file?

Answer (score 532, accepted):

There are two ways. The easy one is to use the `-run` flag and provide a pattern matching names of the tests you want to run.

Example:

```
$ go test packageName -run NameOfTest
```

See the [docs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags) for more info.

Note that the `-run` flag may also run other tests if they contain the string `NameOfTest`, as the `-run` flag matches a regexp.

So to ensure that only a test named exactly 'NameOfTest' is run,
one has to use the regexp `^NameOfTest$`:

```
$ go test -run "^NameOfTest$"
```

The other way is to name the specific file, containing the tests you want to run:

```
$ go test foo_test.go
```

But there's a catch. This works well if:

- `foo.go` is in `package foo`.
- `foo_test.go` is in `package foo_test` and imports 'foo'.

If `foo_test.go` and `foo.go` are the same package (a common case) then you must name all other files required to build `foo_test`. In this example it would be:

```
$ go test foo_test.go foo.go
```

I'd recommend to use the `-run` pattern. Or, where/when possible, always run all package tests.

Comment: would you mind to elaborate on the first (easy) way with `-run` please? I cannot find any manual reference on that one.

Comment: You can also find info about it with `go help testflag`

Comment: When I use the command `go test utils.go utils_test.go` the output is `ok   command-line-arguments 0.002s`. It doesn't run the test. The reason I want to use this test mode is because the package contains many files and they don't compile yet except utils. So I would like to finalize utils before workinqg on other files. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 138):

@zzzz's answer is mostly complete, but just to save others from having to dig through the referenced [documentation](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags) you can run a single test in a package as follows:

```
go test packageName -run TestName
```

Note that you want to pass in the name of the test, *not* the file name where the test exists.

The `-run` flag actually accepts a regex so you could limit the test run to a class of tests. From the docs:

```
-run regexp
    Run only those tests and examples matching the regular
    expression.
```

Comment: Worth noting that package name is the complete package name, e.g "github.com/you/stuff/a/b/c"

Comment: 1.9.3 accepts the relative path of the package too.

Comment: Not sure why, but for some reason, I should specify "./" before the package name

Answer (score 30):

When running a single test I usually do:

```sh
go test -run TestSomethingReallyCool ./folder1/folder2/ -v -count 1
```

`-count 1` also ensures that the test is ran every time instead of being cached. Useful when you are testing against race conditions and have a test that fails only sometimes. In Go versions not using [modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) the same could be achieved by setting `GOCACHE=off` but this interacts poorly with Go modules.

Comment: You can also add the `-race` flag to different go commands like `go test`, to help detect where race conditions happen: https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html

Answer (score 7):

```
go test -v ./<package_name> -run Test
```

Prevents caching of test results.

```
go test -count=1 ./<package_name> -run Test
```

Comment: Quick note, if your cmd line is at the same level as the *_test.go file, you need to prefix the package name with `../<package_name>` instead of `./<package_name>`

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio Code shows a link at the top of a Go test file which lets you run all the tests in just that file.

[image]

In the "Output" window, you can see that it automatically generates a regex which contains all of the test names in the current file:

`Running tool: C:\Go\bin\go.exe test -timeout 30s -run ^(TestFoo|TestBar|TestBaz)$ rootpackage\mypackage`

Note: the very first time you open a Go file in VS Code it automatically offers to install some Go extensions for you.  I assume the above requires that you have previously accepted the offer to install.

Answer (score 5):

```
alias testcases="sed -n 's/func.*\(Test.*\)(.*/\1/p' | xargs | sed 's/ /|/g'"

go test -v -run $(cat coordinator_test.go | testcases)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
go test -v -timeout 30s <path_to_package> -run ^(TestFuncRegEx)
```

- The TestFunc must be inside a `go` test file in that package
- We can provide a regular expression to match a set of test cases or just the exact test case function to run a single test case. For instance `-run TestCaseFunc`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing some issue to run a single specific test from my package this is how I solved

```
go test -v -race ./parsers/xml2csv/stld/ -timeout 30s -run '^Test_stldItemParser_readNodes$'
```

If I run without single quote it wasn't working I use `oh-my-zsh` in `Ubuntu-20.04`

Here

```
-v             for verbosity
-race          to detect race condition
-timeout       for the timeout of the test
```

This are optional can be omitted but good to add.