# Not able to run golang unit tests inside membersrvc/ca

Tags: hyperledger

I  have forked the hyperledger/fabric project and in my repo I tried to run the unit tests for ECA using the following command:
However I get the following error:

> vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.10-37b6688:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/membersrvc/ca$
>   go test eca_test.go
>   command-line-arguments
>    eca_test.go:30:2:
>   cannot find package **"command-/vendor**/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
>   in any of:
>           /opt/go/src/**command-/vendor**/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from $GOROOT)
>           /opt/gopath/src/**command-/vendor**/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from
>   $GOPATH)
>   FAIL    command-line-arguments [setup failed]

Similarly I get the following error when I try to run the CA unit tests:

> vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.10-37b6688:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/membersrvc/ca$ go test ca_test.go
>   command-line-arguments
>   ca_test.go:28:2: cannot find
>   package "command-/vendor/github.com/spf13/viper" in any of:
>           /opt/go/src/command-/vendor/github.com/spf13/viper (from $GOROOT)
>           /opt/gopath/src/command-/vendor/github.com/spf13/viper (from >$GOPATH)
>    FAIL    command-line-arguments [setup failed]

These **USED TO WORK** for me a few days back, but after I updated my fork with the latest changes from hyperledger/project I'm not able to run the test

Here's my GOPATH's value:

> vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.10-37b6688:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ echo $GOPATH /opt/gopath

I'm not sure why golang build system is appending "command-/vendor" to the path when it is looking for imported packages. Could anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation `go test` expects package name as a parameter. 
The should be no issues with tests if you run `go test .` and execute all tests for this package.

It possible to run `go test eca_test.go` but in this case you have to specify all other files required to build ‘eca_test’. See "[How to run test cases in a specified file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935965/how-to-run-test-cases-in-a-specified-file)" for more details.

If you would like to run just one test from this package is better to use `go test . -run TestNewECA` 
“TestNewECA” is the name of test function in eca_test.go, not the file name.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, that seems correct. Just to add, for the benefit of other users..the official way of running  all the unit tests in hyperledger is from the top level directory /hyperledger/fabric by issuing "make unit-test" command