# go test can not load package with command: go test file1_test.go file2.go

Tags: go

I am writing units test. I put all of the test files in other directory. Let's say the folder mypack.

There two files in the folder fun1_test.go and base.go.

The base.go has same common basic functions which are called by fun1_test.go. The base.go looks like:

```
package mypack_test
import (
.....
)

func Base1() {
    // some code
}
```

The func1_test.go has functions which test func1. The func1_test.go looks like:

```
package mypack_test
import (
.....
)

func TestFunc1() {
    // some code
    Base1()
    // some code
}
```

When I use command

```
go test func1_test.go base.go
```

There will be an error:

can't load package: package main: found packages mypack (func1_test.go) and mypack_test (base.go)

Can any one tell me why this happend. I know If the change the file base.go to base_test.go. The command will work ok. But I want to know why.

**UPDATE:**

I notice some of you guys misunderstanding the problem. The problem is not about if the two file need the other packages or one can call one.

The problem is that: If you have **two file** with **same package**, the package name looks like `xxx_test`.  But the two files' name are **yyy_test.go** and **zzz.go**. When using `go test yyy_test.go zzz.go` command, there will be an error said they two file not in same packages.

The error are: can't load package: package main: found packages xxx (yyy_test.go) and xxx_test (zzz.go)

Comment: Are you trying to test code that’s in the `main` package?

Comment: It's possible that you are not including all the packages required to build base.go. Have you seen this question about testing specific files?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935965/how-to-run-test-cases-in-a-specified-file

Comment: @Zak. I updated the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You should follow go's best practices.

That is:

1. Package names should contain only letters with no underscores.
2. Test file should be name of original file + test like: `base.go` - `base_test.go`.
3. Run test by going to packages directory and running `go test`.

If you make those changes, your tests should run without any problems.

Comment: First, Thank you for your. BUt I n=know How to let the files pass. I want to know why it can not pass. Not change file name and the other things let them pass. I also said in my post know how to let them pass.

Answer (score 2):

If you checkout the `go help test` command there is this:

> Test files that declare a package with the suffix "_test" will be
>   compiled as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main
>   test binary.

What is happening is that your file `yyy_test.go` is recognised as a test file because of its `_test.go` ending. The package defined in that file `package xxx_test` is considered to be the test version of the `xxx` package.

See this stack answer for desc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31443271/6376471

Then, along comes `zzz.go` which is not recognised as a test file, because it's missing the `_test.go` suffix, it has a packge `xxx_test` which is *not* considered to be a test package.

This means that essentially you are defining the packages `xxx_test` from `zzz.go` and `xxx` from `yyy_test.go`, even though `yyy_test.go` actually defines `xxx_test`, but it's in a test file so handled differently.

Solutions:

- Identify `zzz.go` as a test file by making it `zzz_test.go`.
- Set `zzz.go` to have the non test package name `package xxx` instead of `package xxx_test`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer