# ignore tests in librd kafka

Tags: go, apache-kafka, dockerfile, librdkafka

My golang project depends on librd kafka

When I try to run `go vet ./...` or `go test ./...` from my jenkin, I get the following error. I beleive that is due to the fact that I am running `./...` but even if I have to ignore the vendor I am not sure what should it be I tried `go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/librdkafka)`  but it didnt help.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1@v1.4.2/kafka/librdkafka/librdkafka_glibc_linux.a(rdkafka_mock_cgrp.o): in function `rd_kafka_mock_cgrp_member_add':

(.text+0x8e5): undefined reference to `__strndup'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1@v1.4.2/kafka/librdkafka/librdkafka_glibc_linux.a(rdkafka_mock_cgrp.o): in function `rd_kafka_mock_cgrp_get':

(.text+0xd1e): undefined reference to `__strndup'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: (.text+0xd46): undefined reference to `__strndup'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1@v1.4.2/kafka/librdkafka/librdkafka_glibc_linux.a(rdkafka_mock_cgrp.o): in function `rd_kafka_mcgrp_rebalance_timer_cb':

(.text+0x13dd): undefined reference to `__strndup'
```

I would like to know how can I get around that  gcc error while test my project

my Dockerfile :

```
FROM golang:1.14-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /src
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
RUN apk add --no-cache git make
RUN go get \
        github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml \
        github.com/axw/gocov \
        github.com/tebeka/go2xunit \
        github.com/wadey/gocovmerge



COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN  go get -d -v ./...
RUN  go mod download

COPY . .

FROM test AS builder
ENV CGO_ENABLED=1
#this config is for lib rd kafka setup
RUN set -ex &&\
    apk add --no-progress --no-cache \
      gcc \
      musl-dev

WORKDIR /src

RUN go install -tags musl ./...
```

My jenkinsfile snippet

```
    stage("Test") {
        agent {
            dockerfile {
                label 'docker'
                additionalBuildArgs '--target test'
                args '-v test:/src/test'
                reuseNode true
            }
        }

        steps {
            parallel(
                    'Unit Test': {
                        sh "make ${makeArgs} test/unit-test"
                    },
                    Coverage: {
                        sh "make ${makeArgs} test/coverage"
                    },
                    Vet: {
                        sh "make ${makeArgs} test/vet"
                    }
            )
        }
        post {
            always {
                junit 'test/*xml'
                publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: false, reportDir: 'test', reportFiles: 'coverage.html', reportName: 'Code Coverage Report'])
                sh "make ${makeArgs} clean"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: use -run flag and specify regex pattern to skip the given vendor. look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808316/6932198), it may help.

Comment: my project has multiple tests and when I am running form the jenkins pipeleine I want to run all the tests within my project and ignore the dependent libradkafka / gcc test. `-run`will help me only it there is a single test I want to run, right.... but I have more than one

Comment: Also for the option ` -run regex` I would have to introduce a unique naming for all my tests so that the regex can pick it up. This  is somehting I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Why not write a bash script that goes to the desired directories and calls `go test`?

Answer (score 3):

I just had to run it `-tags musl`

go vet -tags musl ./...