# --SOLVED-- Golang accessing variable across same package: import cycle not allowed in test, undefined: variable

Tags: go, pgx

My structure is the following:

1. In my `db.go`, I initialize my database

```golang
package database
type Database struct {
    Dbpool *pgxpool.Pool
}
var Db Database
func InitDb() {
    dbpool, err := pgxpool.New(...)
    if err != nil {...} // Check for creating connection
    Db = Database{Dbpool: dbpool}
    greeting, err := Db.GetHelloWorld()
    if err != nil {...} // Check for entering db
}
```

2. In my `queries.go`, I create my handlers like my GetHelloWorldhandler for testing purposes

```golang
package database

func (db *Database) GetHelloWorld() (string, error) {
    var greeting string
    err := db.Dbpool.QueryRow(context.Background(), "select 'Hello, world!'").Scan(&greeting)
    if err != nil {...} // Check for error in selecting Hello World
    return greeting, err
}
```

3. So far everything works as expected. Now in my `queries_test.go`, I like to test my handlers via [dockertest](https://github.com/ory/dockertest) in a separate database.

```golang
package database

var TestDB Database
var dbpool *pgxpool.Pool
 
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // set up docker container, database and its connection
    dbpool, err = pgxpool.New(...)
    // once everything is set up I want to initialize the database like in db.go
    TestDB = Database{Dbpool: dbpool}
}
func Test_GetHelloWorld(t *testing.T) {
    var greeting string
    greeting, err := TestDB.GetHelloWorld()
}
```

Everything works in my `queries_test.go` if I use the `dbpool.QueryRow(context.Background(), "select 'Hello, world!'").Scan(&greeting)` command in my test as it is written down in my handlers but this is not really the sense of testing handlers...

If I run `go test ./queries_test.go` like shown above, I have no compile error but inside my testing container I get the error `undefined: Database`. If I try importing TestDB from db.go like

```golang
import app/database 
var TestDB database.Database
```

I receive the `import cycle not allowed in test`, which I completely understand is not the way of doing it.
So far I assume a third and maybe forth file with an interface might do the job like suggested [here](https://medium.com/@ishagirdhar/import-cycles-in-golang-b467f9f0c5a0) but does it really have to be that complicated?
I feel like there should be a simpler way...
Maybe anyone can help me out?

Comment: What do you mean you “run queries_test.go”? You don’t run files, can you execute `go test`?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant by saying `run queries_test.go`. I corrected it already

Comment: You don’t run individual files, use `go test` without any filename arguments.

Comment: See [`go test`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages) documentation and the documentation relating to the [`[packages]`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns) argument: *"As a special case, if the package list is a list of .go files from a single directory, the command is applied to a single synthesized package __made up of exactly those files__, ignoring any build constraints in those files __and ignoring any other files in the directory__."*

Comment: And the above goes for all top level `go` commands, not just `test`, don’t use filename arguments

Comment: Oh wow never thought this would be my actual problem! Thanks a lot for explaining!
I could not run `go test .` since my `main_test.go` and my `queries_test.go` were in conflict to each other, which was the reason I "isolated" the file by executing only one file.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936314/19932351) helped me to figure out I had to run `go test queries_test.go queries.go db.go` and everything was working fine.
Now I start cleaning up my `main_test.go` to make everything work as expected and finally be able to run `go test .`

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the comments below, I could not run `go test .` since my main_test.go and my queries_test.go were in conflict to each other, which was the reason I "isolated" the file by executing only one file.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936314/19932351) helped me to figure out I had to run `go test queries_test.go queries.go db.go` and everything was working fine.

The main solution of course was to solve the dependency conflict between both files.